# Is there a way to target the button on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
swal({
    title: "Number of Players",
    type: "input",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
},  function(inputValue){
        playersNum = Number(inputValue);
        if(inputValue == 1){
            swal("Nice!"," ", "success")
        } else if(inputValue == 2){
            swal("Twice as Nice!"," ", "success");
        } else
            swal(":(", "Enter a 1 or 2 of Players", "error");
    });

$(".confirm:button").click(function() {
  alert( "testing" );
});
```

I have this fancy code from http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/
This snippet pops up a dialogue box to get a number, that box has an "ok" button to close and proceed. Once that "ok" is clicked, another box pops up with a cool checkmark animation and another "ok" button to close. These "ok" buttons are being added dynamically and have the same class. Is there a way for me to target ONLY the second "ok" button with jQuery or vanilla js? the jQuery I have above targets both instances of that "ok" button and as such the alert pops up twice.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$(".confirm:button")` should return you an array with two items. You should be able to add the click handler to the first one: `$(".confirm:button")[0].click(function() {`

Comment: when I add the index 0 to the click handler, the pop up boxes now just flash on for half a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dz9aLvyg/)

```
swal({
    title: "Number of Players",
    type: "input",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    animation: "slide-from-top",
},  function(inputValue){
        playersNum = Number(inputValue);
        if(inputValue == 1)
        {
            swal("Nice!"," ", "success");
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $("button.confirm").click(function()
                {
                    alert("this is OK number 2");

                    // here do what you want when you click on the seconde OK button

                });
            },250);
        } else if(inputValue == 2)
        {
            swal("Twice as Nice!"," ", "success");
        } else
            swal(":(", "Enter a 1 or 2 of Players", "error");
    });

$(".confirm:button").click(function() {
  console.log( "testing" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According the the docs, you can add a custom class to the button, that being the case, just target that class in your jquery click function.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, really new to js